# Is there a tool to check scripts loading order in html

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When I write `<script>` in my index.html I have been hit more than once by the loading order, i.e, something not working because one dependency library is loaded after the library depends on it.

Is there a tool I can use to check the loading order, I guess that equals to a tool checks javascript library dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google Chrome, open inspect element (right click and click inspect) and click on the Network tab, it should list the order and loading times of all resources (including javascript). :)
I would suspect there would be a similar feature for Firefox.